# How to sum of arrays of floating point numbers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

How to sum of arrays of floating point numbers..as the results from distance that the array float come from results `Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results);` method in Google maps api ,,i'm trying with this, but at some point it decrease, it should always incrementing. what am i missing?

**EDIT**:

```
public float total(ArrayList<LatLng> listPoints){
        if(listPoints.size()==2){
            listPoints.clear();
        }
        listPoints.add(latLng);
        float[] results = new float[2];
        float sum  = 0.0f;
        for (int z = 0; z < listPoints.size(); z++) {
            if(listPoints.size() == 1){
                latStart = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
                longStart = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
                Toast.makeText(this, "listPoint 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(listPoints.size() == 2){
                latB = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
                longB = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
                Toast.makeText(this, "listPoint 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results);
            sum+=results[0];
        }
        tvJarakTotal.setText(sum + "");
        return sum;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
the distance came from `onLocationChanged()` method as the user location is moving,

**EDIT**:
I Finally find the solution myself, by creating some trick using sharedPreference. but the accepted answer is correct to the question.

Comment: Your method makes no sense.  You need _four_ points to get a distance from this API, and your `listPoints` list just represents a single collection of points.  Where are the destinations?

Comment: when i display the Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results); it gives ex: 0.35612  ,  1.23465  , 3.53223  , and so on..   , i can see the start and the destination ,  i try to save it in variable results[z] then i add it with next float number .. what am i missing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you think you were doing in your code above.  First of all, the `Location#distanceBetween` API takes in a *pair* of latitude longitude values, i.e. two geographic points, and then returns the distance between them in `results[0]` (q.v. the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))).

Next, it isn't clear what the starting and ending points are intended to be.  I answered below under the assumption that the `listPoints` are one set of points (either starting or ending), and the vales `latB` and `longB` are a fixed set of starting/ending points.  Without this assumption, an answer really can't be given here.

```
public float total(ArrayList<LatLng> listPoints) {
    float[] results;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (int z=0; z < listPoints.size(); z++) {
        double latStart = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
        double longStart = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
        Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results);
        sum += results[0];
        tvJarak.setText(sum + "");
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: i edit my code in question, kindly check it please,..is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look your code carefully.

```
float[] results = new float[listPoints.size()];
```

`results` variable is declared as a local variable but it's not initialized with any values yet.
In this case it has random value.

That's why `sum` gives random minus value.

Comment: Normally this might be true, but the API should fill in at least the first slot of `results` with a distance.  The problem is that the OP is iterating over the entire array, which is the wrong size, and likely summing in garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] results = new float[listPoints.size()];
```

In this case your result array stored size of the listPoints array. After that you are trying to iterate result array by using listPointers array size.

Assume your :-  `float [] results = new [2];`

Now you try to add up same value again and again inside you for a loop. Please make sure your scenario is correct or not.

You should store api date someware inside your code. like this:

```
lat = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
long = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
```

if you want you can do it like this,

```
public float total(ArrayList<LatLng> listPoints) {
    float[] results;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    float lat = 0.0f, long = 0.0f;
    for (int z=0; z < listPoints.size(); z++) {
        lat = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
        long = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
        Location.distanceBetween(lat, long, latB, longB, results);
        sum+=results[z];
        tvJarak.setText(sum + "");
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: this is i edit, is this correct? it should incrementing always, but in some point it decrease. what am i missing?  https://pastebin.com/6CP36eaN

Comment: It's so harder to see the problem here. If you can please share the whole code here. If I got something I'll share with you.

Comment: I think you should remove this line : else **if(listPoints.size() == 2){
                latB = listPoints.get(z).latitude;
                longB = listPoints.get(z).longitude;
                Toast.makeText(this, "listPoint 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }**